# Is there any relationship between un-allocated disk space and speed in Windows?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, performance, disk-space

In my computer I only allocated half of my hard disk space for usage; other space remains un-allocated.

I wonder: will this decrease or improve my CPU performance?

My assumption was if I provide low disk space we can get higher performance because of actual scan area is small. Or is there any mapping mechanism to handle High hard drive spaces.

Comment: i think it scans an index to find things and so probably wont be much slower on a hard drive that is much larger.  But if a HDD is too full like not enough space for virtual memory then the comp slows down. There is a prgram people used to use  and might still, called defrag that might speed things up by shifting things around so maybe there is something to consider re how it works and how performance can be affected. You may want to read about that. I am rusty though

Comment: I have used windows de-fragment tool and known about what happening when we do fragment. Re arranging isolated files in-order reduce disk head's read and write travel time. isn't it? is that virtual memory having that capability to handle these large and small scale  hard drive mapping.

Comment: Please don't abuse `\`code\`` or `> quote` for formatting, and please do not highlight random words.

Comment: virtual memory has nothing to do with those terms you just made up 'small scale hard drive mapping' is a term you made up, don't do that. Virtual memory is for when you run out of RAM then hard drive space is used.

Answer (score 0):

when you do a search on Windows the system  indexes all the files.. This means that it makes a record of all the files and the free space on the drive.. So it doesn't matter how much is the free space on the drive because once it is recorded in system index.. The system won't go throw it again..

What really helps speed up things is the defragmentation (just right click the drive .. Go to proprieties then tools .. And optimize) & also make sure that on the properties general tab the indexing option is checked ;)

So all in all .. Your unallocated space doesn't do you any good or harm ;)

Comment: "You don’t need to manually defragment a modern operating system." from [HTG Explains: Do You Really Need to Defrag Your PC?](http://www.howtogeek.com/97723/htg-explains-do-you-really-need-to-defrag-your-pc/)